# git clone command for uri with special chars

Tags: git, uri, git-clone

im trying to execute git clone command in one line :

git clone https://user%40mail.com:seckey@https://hostname.com/_git/project%20name

i got an error : Could not resolve host: https

when i execute :

git clone https://hostname.com/_git/project%20name

and enter the user name and pass manually everything is working but when i do it in one line i get an error

i guess the problem with the URL or with the %20 in the URI coz the project name have space in it . 
tried adding "" or '' didnt help 
any ideas ?

thanks !

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638505/git-clone-ssh-with-spaces-in-username-path-and-different-drive

Comment: Nothing from this post worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `https://` twice in your clone URL. Remove `https://` after the `@` sign:

```
git clone https://user%40mail.com:seckey@hostname.com/_git/project%20name
```

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks !

Comment: The funny thing in another scenario it works with 2 https

Comment: I also thought that the second https may be erroneous, but then I thought maybe it is such a setup ... doh