# "Does not appear to be a git repository" when trying to clone via SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I have a Windows 10 machine running that I would like to host a git repo on. OpenSSH is running and I am able to SSH into the machine via Powershell, so it is connectable.

I created a new git on that machine in a folder named Test via

```
git init --shared --bare
```

I'm now trying to clone using Sublime Merge with the source URL like so:

```
ssh://USER@IP:/Test
```

However, after I put in my password, I get two errors:

```
fatal: "/Test" does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

I've tried googling with both issues but have not gotten anything that has helped. Is anyone able to help?

Edit: I can clone, commit, and push locally on the remote machine, so it definitely is a git repo.

Edit #2: FIXED. Followed this guide on how to point directly to a git folder by forcing the repo to use powershell (very bottom) https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-Win32_OpenSSH

> **Note that git clone user@domain@servermachine:C:/test/myrepo.git does not work due to known issue. Work around it to set powershell as
> default Shell in registry. Or by following steps when cmd is default
> shell:
>
> ```
> cd c:\mygitrepros
> # initialize a local repo folder
> git init mylocalrepo
> cd mylocalrepo
> # add the remote repro
> git remote add origin user@domain@servermachine:C:/test/myrepo.git
> # work around the known issue by launching powershell to run the git commands
> git config --local remote.origin.uploadpack "powershell git-upload-pack"
> git config --local remote.origin.receivepack "powershell git-receive-pack"
> ```

git fetch origin

Comment: `--shared` is not recommended in the docs unless you know what you're doing. It's also only for local clones, ie not over ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Comment: ssh servers generally start file access from the specific user's directory, so `ssh://user@ip/foo` means "file `foo` in home directory of user `user`". To access `/Test` you need `ssh://user@ip//Test`.

Comment: @torek it appears Windows may be the exception that proves the rule :/

Comment: @CervEd: Windows usually is  It seems odd that this ["known issue"](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/895) has been open since 2017 (!)

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a complete tutorial how to hast a repo.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

That repo is for linux but i think the steps should be similar. When you create a Bare-Repository with:

```
$ cd /srv/git
$ mkdir project.git
$ cd project.git
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/git/project.git/
```

It's common to name the folder with `.git`. But after that you should be able to clone with the following command.

```
git clone git@gitserver:/srv/git/project.git
```

So you have add the path to the Git-Folder. I think that is your problem. You try only the path "/Test" from your Root-Directory. That could be wrong and Git tell you that this folder is not a Git-Repository.

Comment: I (thought) the git folder was in the root path. Do you know if this would be C:/, C:/Users/UserName, or a different path for Windows 10?

Comment: I don't know i work only with Linux. Otherwise there are a lot of Git servers for Windows. Perhaps you install a system like gitea for example. Then you have a platform where you can add repos and you get everything you need.

Comment: I'll definitely look into Gitea. I'm not sure if is a path issue, as now I'm just trying to do the full path (based off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638505/git-clone-ssh-with-spaces-in-username-path-and-different-drive) and it stills throws an error: `git clone ssh://USER@IP:/C/FOLDER/Test.git`

Comment: Just in case you were curious, it definitely was a path issue (and still have no idea what the default path is on the server). Followed what was outlined in this link, and was able to point specifically to C:/FOLDER/Test.git and was able to pull it: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-Win32_OpenSSH